# How to create OVERFLOW DROPDOWN MENU in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, overflow

Am new to android, could some one tell me how to create " **OVERFLOW DROP DOWN MENU** " in android. I learnt about creating popup menu something like   [this](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=6138633541415) 
 , but what I need is something like  [this](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1513863347773)

For this should I have to create custom Menu bar at the top(Action Bar) with some xml ? i.e. if I put a button with three dots at the top right of menu bar, what should I have to put into the **OnClickListener Method** *?*

Here is a code snippet which I tried out for the above requirement which resulted in couple of errors.

```
     try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if(menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

*Please Note I had put above code into OnCreate Method.*

P.S. Overflow menu should display even if there are not many sub items at the menu bar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply above hack you can do like this

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_more_button"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@string/menu_more_action">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/jumpToPage"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_jumptopage"
                    android:showAsAction="never"
                    android:title="@string/menu_jump_to_page"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/browse_movie_refresh_menu_button"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_refresh"
                    android:showAsAction="never"
                    android:title="@string/menu_reload_movies"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
```

this is from my project if you need assistant you can ask

Comment: Can you give more details about using above hack, i.e should I have to put above snippet into menu.xml ? What about **Activity** & **Java Class** ? I tried out as I said above it resulted in auto kill of App.